# Git keep staged changes

Tags: git, github

How do I keep my staged changes without committing and work on other issue's where these changes are not required ?

I have created a branch say b1 and made some changes and staged that changes. Now I had an urgent issue which I need to work on but I don't require the staged changes here. So I switched to branch b2 and fetched and pulled from upstream. But the staged changes still exists in the b2 branch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not stage, but [*stash*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) the changes. You can then later apply them again to your working copy:

```
git stash
git checkout -b urgent-issue
git commit
git checkout -
git stash pop
```

Comment: Note that `git stash` makes *two* temporary commits (neither of which is on any branch): one contains the current index, i.e., includes whatever you have staged now, and the other contains the current work-tree, i.e., includes whatever you have not-staged.  When you go to put the stash back in place, you can recover the staged and not-staged states separately, using `git stash apply --index` or `git stash pop --index`.  (I always use `apply` since I have a habit of misspelling `--index` and using `apply` lets me retry with the correct spelling.)

Comment: Any choices you made during staging are lost in this manner, and you have to redo these.

Comment: @john16384 in the case that you need to keep the state of your index, you can specify the `--keep-index` option

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to the answer given by @knittl is to actually go ahead and make a *temporary* commit (keep reading):

```
git commit -m 'WIP'
git checkout urgent-issue
```

Once you have committed your work, your working directory will be clean and you can switch branches as you need.  When you want to return to your current branch, you can continue the work and amend the temporary commit you made.

```
git checkout feature   # return to original branch
# work work ... complete the commit
git commit --amend -m 'Finished the work I started earlier'
```

I usually prefer making a temporary commit over a stash when I have critical work for several reasons.  First, it eliminates the need to have to sort through the stash stack looking for the stash I want to apply (and it easy to let the stack pile up with old junk).  Second, because I know that I have a commit with unfinished work, it forces discipline on me to complete the feature.

Comment: You can also use `git reset --soft HEAD^` (keeps items staged) or `git reset --mixed HEAD^` (unstages) to get back to your previous state.  The advantage to using `git stash` is that it makes *two* temporary commits, which may be what you want; see comment I am about to add to knittl's answer.

Comment: @torek I learned more from your comments than from the answers.

Comment: BTW I prefer the temporary commit method in general, although for some situations I will use `git stash`.  But `git stash` has an annoying bug: if you add (stage) a change, then make the work-tree version of the same file match the `HEAD` version of that file, `git stash apply --index` *restores the wrong version of the file* to the work-tree.  I reported this bug and proposed a fix on the Git mailing list years ago and no one has bothered to fix it.

Comment: I also have this general feeling about `git stash`, so I tend to avoid it.  Another plus about a temporary commit is that it makes it easy to share whatever partial work you might have with, e.g., another team member.  Thanks for the really great insights on this question.

Answer (score -1):

```
# No need to stage
# put your current changes in stash
git stash

# create and checkout to b1 branch
git checkout -b b2

# resolve urgent issue and push changes 

# now get back to branch b1
git checkout b1

# Apply stashed changes back
git stash pop
```